# Merge 2 Repos: Same project but has different repos

Tags: git, git-merge

I'd like to ask if anyone tried working with this scenario.

I have 2 different source controls. The first source control repository is the parent while the second repository is the child. Both repositories have the same project and has its own remote repo but the child has more updated files compare to the parent. I'm planning to merge the child to the parent but the problem is, they are different repositories. Any help?

Comment: To provide a good answer, we have to know if these 2 repos are remote ones (you will need a local repo to make the sync by adding remotes for the 2 repos, fetch, do the sync and push the result)  or 2 local ones (Add one as a remote of the other, fetch, do the sync and push) or a 1 remote and 1 local. Please update your question  with a better description so that someone could give you a good answer...

Comment: Basically, the answer is having the 2 histories in the same repo (by adding remote and fetching) and update the branches like you want it to be and push the result where you want it to be updated...

Comment: Yes @Philippe they have different remote repos

Comment: in a quick-n-dirty nutshell `git clone <parent_repo_url> && cd <your_project> && git remote add child <child_repo_url> && git fetch --all`. To get a child branch to parent repo (i.e. `origin` by default): `git checkout <branch_from_child> && git push origin <branch_from_child>`. And the other way arround: `git checkout <branch_from_parent> && git push child <branch_from_parent>`

Comment: @atmospheric when you say "different repos" do you simply mean "different repository locations" (similar to a fork on GitLab/GitHub) or are they repositories with independent history? The former only requires a one-time `pull` (or `fetch`+`merge`), the latter is more difficult (and not guaranteed to work). Please provide the info whether or not both repos share history or are independent.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that both your repository share a common history, i.e.

- Repo A commits: a-b-c-d
- Repo B commits: a-b-e-f

A commit in Git always references its direct parent or parents. It does not matter whether a commit is part of repository A or B. Usually, such repositories are called *fork* (cf. GitLab or GitHub UIs), but for Git it does not really matter.

Therefore, to merge the history of two repositories, add one to the other as remote, then merge the history (just like you would with a regular branch):

```sh
git clone server.com/repoA
cd repoA
git add remote b server.com/repoB
git fetch b
git merge b/branch_to_merge
```

After `git fetch b` your local clone will contain the history of both repositories: history of A in implicit remote `origin`, history of B in remote `b`. `git merge b/branch_to_merge` then merges the branch of repository b into your *current* branch of your clone (most likely `master` or `main`). Make sure to switch branches beforehand if you need to merge into a different branch.

To visualize the history, you could run `gitk --all` right after the fetch step to see how the commits of both repositories are related.